# Changing a Labels value in Javascript after being passed into a function

Tags: javascript, function, label

I am trying to make a function for java script that evaluates the text within a form and updates a label next to the form with either Valid entry or Invalid entry.

I have the code working here so far

```
function validateText(form) {       

if(form.value == '') {
  document.getElementById("reasonLabel").innerHTML =  "Invalid Entry";
  return false;
}
else{document.getElementById("reasonLabel").innerHTML =  "Invalid Entry";}

var re = /^[\w ]+$/;

if(!re.test(form.value)) {
  document.getElementById("reasonLabel").innerHTML =  "Invalid Entry";
  return false;
}

document.getElementById("reasonLabel").innerHTML =  "Valid Entry";
return true; }
```

However I want to use this function and apply it to all forms inside my html each form has a corresponding label next to it.

My question is how do I pass in a label and edit its value without using .getElementByID()

Sorry if this is an obvious question I am very new to javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the label (which had to have been gotten using `document.getElementById()` or something similar in the first place), you can use it as a normal variable, like in the following:

```
function validateText(form, label) {       

    if(form.value == '') {            
        label.innerHTML =  "Invalid Entry";
        return false;                 
    }                                 
    else{                             
        label.innerHTML =  "Invalid Entry";
    }                                 

    var re = /^[\w ]+$/;              

    if(!re.test(form.value)) {        
        label.innerHTML =  "Invalid Entry";
        return false;                 
    }                                 

    label.innerHTML =  "Valid Entry"; 
    return true;                      
}
```

Then `label` could be gotten by passing something like `document.getElementById("reasonLabel")` into the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the label's DOM object (returned from `getElementByID`) as a parameter, just like any other value.